# execute an if statement via commandline

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am running a python program via cron that runs every 1 minute. Occasionally, it will eat up a lot of CPU and I need the next cron job to not run if that's the case. I am trying

`` if (( `~/cpu_usage.txt` < 60 )); then `cd /path/to/program && python myfile.py 100`; fi ``

`myfile` has a `print bob_here` in the file and that causes the above to crash with:

`bob_here: command not found`

The `myfile.py` runs perfectly fine on it's own so the issue is with the if statement. How do I get it the script to execute properly?

Note: Probably not too important here but `cpu_usage.txt` is a simple bash program to print out the current cpu usage:

```
echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just lose the ticks and provide the full path to the python interpreter:

```
if (( `~/cpu_usage.txt` < 60 )); then python /path/to/program/myfile.py 100; fi
```

You don't need the ticks as the shell will execute the command following the `then` keyword as designed; the ticks will launch a sub-shell and the result/output is then used as command for the `if-then`, which is not what you want here:

```
> if true; then echo OK; fi
> OK
> if true; then `echo OK`; fi
> OK: command not found
```

Edit: from my experience, if you want to use it with crontab, it works best to if you place all your commands in a shell script and call that from crontab instead.

Comment: Seems to run fine when I run it manually but doesn't work on crontab

Answer (score 0):

Maybe break it down into just

```
if (( $(vmstat 1 2|awk 'END{print 100-$15}') < 60 )); then
    cd /path/to/my/program && ./python myfile.py 100
fi
```